# Can't save more than one record in array PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

So I'm wondering how to save more than one record in array from html form? I mean today I had a task to make PHP/HTML script where user can add goods to array via html form. My problem was that I couldn't save more than one record in array, they were overwriting each time I pushed `"submit"` button.
To get more clear with situation here is the code(It's just an example):

```
<?php
$array=array();
array_push($array, $_POST['name']);
foreach($labas as $hi){
    echo $hi . "\n";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<body> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
 Name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="name"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

So each time I enter name and push `submit` button, php script displays only the last record I submitted. I tried to use `$array[]=$value` still the same.
I know there is a solution with `session_start()` and using `database` but can I solve it without using it? I bet there is a way, can you guys help me out?

Comment: it is because `$array` initialize with blank `array` every time you submit form.

Comment: No they are not overwriting the array. The array does not stay in existance between executions of the script. You have to put the array in the $_SESSION for that to happen

Comment: Definitely, as everytime the page refreshes and the relationship goes out. So, better to use `SESSION` or `DB` operation to achieve what you want.

Comment: In normal case, this approach will not work. Because PHP page will clear all previous data on each page refresh. The submit action will refresh the page. U must need session or database access to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I left `$array=array();` by mistake while editing my own code, but It's not the problem. Moving it out it still stays the same. Thank you guys for you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not overwriting the array. The array does not stay in existance between executions of the script. Remember web sites are StateLess.

You have to put the array in the $_SESSION for that to happen as the Session array provides a web site with some State, by keeping the session array between executions of a script. PHP does this for you, when you call `session_start()` PHP goes and get the session data associated with this connection to the client.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['name']) ){
        // the user hit submit
        $_SESSION['all_names'][] = $_POST['name'];
    }

    foreach($_SESSION['all_names'] as $name){
        echo $name . "\n";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
    <body> 
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
           Name:<br>
           <input type="text" name="name"><br>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I was wrong, there is no other way. Thank you for your explanation, mate! :) Have a good day! :)